# Windows cmd not terminating even after killing the task

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have below bat script which will invoke a python script

```
start "MyScript" py -3 "C:\test.py"
```

But when I try to abort it from another cmd I face an issue as no tasks running and I see my python script running in the background  with cmd open with title "Myscript"

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq MyScript"
```

INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.

Comment: can you please explain here and let me know how we can kill the Myscript title window

Comment: Do you understand what the `start` command does? Do you know what `py` is supposed to be? and what it does? Your batch file is running in an instance of cmd.exe, this is launching another instance which in turn is launching py.exe, which in turn is launching the latest installed 3x version of python.exe and passing to that a .py file as an argument. Until you have understood the processes occurring, you will be unlikely to identify or control the particular process you are seeking to control.